# ImportError: No module named serial in windows 7 python 2.7 and python 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install python serial driver. I have done some steps as follows:

I installed the pyserial-2.7.win32.exe on my pc;

I wrote this python file.

```
#coding=gb18030

import serial
import time
import random
class EMCTest: 
   def __init__(self, Port="COM25"): # Port =3: COM4(According To You PC Environment, It Needs to Be Changed Before Testing.)
       self.l_serial = None
       self.port = Port
```

When I run *.py file in python 2.7 I get the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\davwang\Desktop\X100.py", line 4, in <module>
import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

Comment: `pip install pyserial` worked for me.  Look in your site-packages to see if it was actually installed in the python version you expect it to be.

Comment: Maybe my pc have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.3 together. On another computer, I only installed python 2.7 and pyserial-2.7.win32.exe. The code works well. Why ? I donot know!

Comment: I'd recommend against using installers to manage installs.  You should look into using pip and virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed successfully on the computer which yesterday failed.  The pip method and virtual environments, I will continue to research. You are good guy !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with nearly all imported modules. I couldn’t figure it out, because using pip install was what i have done all the time. I solches with a very nasty and unelegant way

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, u'/…/…/…/python2.7/site-packages')
```

I believe that there is another way, but i haven’t found one in weeks and this actually worked for me.

Comment: What python implementation are you using? CPython? IronPython? Also, you should `sys.path.append()`. It is the recommended way to append.

Answer (score 2):

A few things could be wrong. Is your Python x86 or x64? Did the installer actually install (look in site-packages).

Instead of doing complicated work finding what's wrong with your install,  try installing with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) the easiest way to install libraries. Use `pip install pyserial`. This is widely considered the best way to install Python libraries. It automatically deals with dependencies, operating system and x86 versus x64.

EDIT: It looks to me that the python folder isn't in your system path. You can `sys.path.append("/path/to/python/")`, or you can run `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;<Path/to/python>` in cmd.

Comment: How to type "pip install pyserial", in cmd or shell ?I want to know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: press the windows key and r (`win+r`) and type "cmd" and press enter. from there you should check if you have pip installed by typing `pip freeze`. If you get an error, it isn't installed, if you get a listing of libraries, it is, an you can type `pip install pyserial`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) for how to install pip.

Comment: Yes, I get and error , 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. How to do next?

Comment: The link to pip is in my answer. The website has you download get pip.py and run it. It should automatically install pip.