# Python ImportError - Custom Module

Tags: python, twilio, python-import, python-3.5

I have installed a custom module (Twilio) using PIP, but when I try to `import` it, it will bring up:

```
ImportError: No module named 'twilio'
```

I'm running Windows 10 and Python 3.5. What am I missing? It seems to be an error with the paths. If it is, how do I set the paths?

Edit: I have my PYTHONHOME set to C:\Python33 and my PYTHONPATH set to C:Python33\Lib

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Windows. I'll fix the question :)

Comment: That simply means its not installed correctly or the path has not been set

Comment: @dnit13 So how do I set the path?

Comment: did you try pip show package_name

Comment: @dnit13 Just tried, pip doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: did you try importing in cmd ? and which python version are you using?

Comment: @dnit13 I've tried importing in code and in cmd, and python 3.5

Comment: If you have python 2 in your PC, check if you didnt install twilio into that instead of 3

Comment: Whatever directory you installed it to is not in `sys.path`.  Move it to one of the directories in that list.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, how do you do that?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I don't have python 2, but good point!

Comment: or append that directory to sys.path

Comment: @dnit13 Can I please have the cliff notes on how?

Comment: go through these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599872/python-windows-importerror-no-module-named-site , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335859/importerror-no-module-named-serial-in-windows-7-python-2-7-and-python-3-3 . you are likely to find your solution.

Comment: @dnit13 I have done the things suggested in those questions, and it isn't helping. Sorry!

Comment: Please provide the output for your pip show package_name and sys.path or try with easy_install

Comment: @dnit13 I can't copy and paste the command prompt for pip show package_name, but it displays the location as C:\Python33\lib\site-packages, and I'm not sure what you mean by sys.path.

Comment: @dnit13 Sorry if I'm being really stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check your package location.

```
pip show custom_package
```

Then check the system paths by

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If you dont' see your package path here, you can add it.

```
sys.path.append(custom_package_path)
```

If this doesn't work try reinstalling it. Or you can also install it with easy_install

Comment: Oh wow, turns out there's a whole different directory. I need to path back to the one I'm using. Thanks for the help, I hope this works!

Comment: It worked! However, I need to append this at the top of all my programs. Is there a quick and dirty way of editing the path for all of my programs?

Comment: @linky0064: Install it to one of the directories in `sys.path`, or use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).